# How to do [UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:] prior to iOS5?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimage

The following code tiles the image area within the specified insets:

```
UIEdgeInsets imgInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.f, 5.f, 13.f, 44.f);
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"fileName"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:imgInsets];
```

However this is only available in iOS5. How can I achieve the same result for before-iOS5 compatibility?

`[UIImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: topCapHeight:]` is not appropriate as far as I understand, because it assumes that the tile-able area is 1px wide. In other words it doesn't tile, it streches. Therefore it doesn't work with patterns, only with single-color images. This is demonstrated in the screenshot below.

Then there is `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]`, but this assumes that the entire image needs to be tiled, it doesn't allow for insets that must remain capped.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

.

[image]

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. On the one hand, hooray that they fixed it in iOS 5. On the other hand, I'm struggling to think of a straightforward way to add this functionality so it works in iOS 4. What did you decide to do?

Comment: Was it the case perhaps that prior to this feature graphic designers were just very busy building buttons?!

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for a solution to this too. At this point I think I'll use `respondsToSelector:@selector(resizableImageWithCapInsets:)` on the original UIImage to see if the method is available. If not, then use stretchable image.

I'm still looking for a better solution, and if one comes up, I'll update the answer.